# webpack 5 image is not loading with `reactjs`

Tags: reactjs, webpack

here is my webpack.config:

```
const HtmlPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const path = require("path");
module.exports = {
    watch: true,
    output:{
        path:path.resolve(__dirname, "build"),
        filename:"bundle.js"
    },
    module:{
        rules:[
            {
                test:/\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude:/node_modules/,
                use:[{loader:"babel-loader"}]
            },
            {
                test:/\.html$/,
                use:[{loader:"html-loader"}]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
                use: [{loader: 'file-loader'}],
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins:[
        new HtmlPlugin({
            filename:"index.html",
            template:"./src/index.html"
        })
    ],
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    devServer:{
        historyApiFallback:true,
        port:5000
    }
}
```

i am importing image in index.js:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Img from "./images/flower.jpg"; 

const App = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Hello World!!</h1>
            <img src="{Img}" />
        </div>
    )
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

But when i start the app, no images loaded.
it looks like:

[image: No image loaded]

and getting some warring message like :

`"webpack performance recommendations:  You can limit the size of your bundles by using import() or require.ensure to lazy load some parts of your application. For more info visit https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/"`

how to solve this? I use    `"webpack": "^5.11.0", "webpack-cli": "^4.2.0",`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if you copied you code wrong, but it is not correct. You put `"{Img}"` between quotes, but it should be without: `{Img}`

**Wrong:**

```
import Img from "./images/flower.jpg"; 

const App = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Hello World!!</h1>
            <img src="{Img}" /> <-- HERE IT IS NOT A VARIABLE
        </div>
    )
};
```

**Correct:**

```
import Img from "./images/flower.jpg"; 


const App = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Hello World!!</h1>
            <img src={Img} /> <-- WITHOUT "" IT IS A VARIABLE
        </div>
    )
};
```

See:
https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-poincare-5yvcn

Answer (score 5):

The Webpack 5 docs state that you can use the built in asset modules, so you don't need `file-loader`: https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-management/#loading-images

In your webpack config file, change your image handling rule to:

```
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
        type: 'asset/resource',
      },
```

In `index.js`, change `<img src="{Img}" />` to `<img src={Img} />` (as Magofoco suggested).